# Using subsets and whole dataframes simultaneously in a loop

Tags: r, if-statement, apply

I'm trying to write a function that loops over rows of a dataframe and uses information about other rows to determine the output for each loop.

Consider the following dataframe, which is meant to represent people who have a longitude coordinate, a latitude coordinate, and a value to represent if they are or are not sick:

```
game.mat<-as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 100, ncol = 3))
colnames(game.mat)<-c("PosX","PosY","Sick")
game.mat[,"PosX"]<-sample(x = c(1:100), 100, replace = TRUE)
game.mat[,"PosY"]<-sample(x = c(1:100), 100, replace = TRUE)
game.mat[,"Sick"]<-sample((c(rep(0,8),rep(1,2))),100,replace=TRUE)
```

Some minority of people will be sick at baseline. My function is meant to infect people who have neighboring x-y coordinates with a sick person (so anyone who is adjacent to someone who is sick). I considered embedding a function like this in an ifelse statement:

```
 search_sick<-function(d,corx,cory){
   d2<-d[d$PosX<corx+2&d$PosX>corx-2&d$PosY<cory+2&d$PosY>cory-2,]
   if(sum(d2$Sick>0)){
    d$Sick<-1
   } else{
    d$Sick<-0
   }
  }
```

But it makes everyone sick, perhaps because it gives everyone a value of 1 if anyone is next to a sick person. I also considered using an apply function. But from what I understand about apply, it will only operate within the a single row at a time so it will be impossible to retrieve information about whether other rows have neighboring coordinate values.

I hope this makes sense. Happy to provide any additional information.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic you're trying to use. Are `corx` and `cory` meant to be a single point in space that the user inputs into the function? Or do you want to search around all infected individuals simultaneously? Or something else? I've given a solution to the first case below, but if that's not what you intended let me know.

Comment: I want to search around all infected individuals simultaneously. That was the problem I was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using `apply`

```
set.seed(1)

game.mat<-as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 100, ncol = 3))
colnames(game.mat)<-c("PosX","PosY","Sick")
game.mat[,"PosX"]<-sample(x = c(1:100), 100, replace = TRUE)
game.mat[,"PosY"]<-sample(x = c(1:100), 100, replace = TRUE)
game.mat[,"Sick"]<-sample((c(rep(0,8),rep(1,2))),100,replace=TRUE)

#plot the sick individuals in red
plot(PosY~PosX, data=game.mat, col=as.factor(Sick), pch=16)
```

[image: before]

We'll modify your function to have a flexible search radius "r", and to return the indices of the newly infected individuals

```
search_sick<-function(d, corx, cory, r){
  indx<-which(d$PosX<corx+r & d$PosX>corx-r & d$PosY<cory+r & d$PosY>cory-r)
}

contagious<-game.mat[game.mat$Sick==1,]

infected<-apply(contagious, 1, function(x) {
  search_sick(game.mat, x[1], x[2], r=10)
})

game.mat$T1<-game.mat$Sick

game.mat$T1[unique(unlist(infected))]<-1

#circle points which have become sick
points(PosY~PosX, data=game.mat[game.mat$Sick==0 & game.mat$T1==1,], col="red", cex=2)
```

[image: after]

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice and elegant approach. Though ideally, I would be able to easily loop through the rows of the dataframe, feed the function the coordinates of all sick individuals, and run the function independently for those coordinates while continuously updating the dataframe. This is especially important as the function is embedded in a for-loop so I need the coordinates to be automatically fed in rather than inputting them myself.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I have updated my answer accordingly.